# How do I normalize this URL in powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the following code for Azure key vault resources:

```
$tempkeyid = (Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $vaultname -Name $tempkeyname).Id
$tempkeyid = $tempkeyid.Substring(0, $tempkeyid.LastIndexOf('/'))
$tempkeyid
New-AzSynapseWorkspaceKey -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup -WorkspaceName $workspacename -Name $tempkeyname -EncryptionKeyIdentifier $tempkeyid
```

Line 2 is there because the key vault returns the versioned identifier but line 4 needs the versionless identifier

The value for $tempkeyid in line 3 is:

```
https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net:443/keys/keyname
```

I get the error:

```
New-AzSynapseWorkspaceKey: Key Vault URL should be a normalized URL
```

I've tried to encode and decode the URL with the code below but the encode attempt gets the same error and the decode attempt gets an error that says "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined". I'm not sure how to normalize it otherwise, or what specifically isn't normalized.  The value of $tempkeyid looks correct to me.

```
$tempkeyid = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($tempkeyid) 
$tempkeyid = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($tempkeyid)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding is not the same as URI normalisation which refers to expressing the uri in a standard format. (See [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization)). In your case, I would guess it doesn't like the use of the default port (:443). To systematically get a normalised uri, try something like this:

```
$tempkeyiduri = [System.Uri]($tempkeyid)
$tempkeyid = $tempkeyiduri.AbsoluteUri
```